# Unity - CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

At first, I can build my game normally. Then I import firebase and code this to my script to call database in firebase. I run game in Unity and it has data in firebase.

```
void Start()
{
    // Set up the Editor before calling into the realtime database.
    //FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://lively-option-113515.firebaseio.com/");
}
IEnumerator LoadData() {

    //yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.1f);
    string wwwtext = "";

    if (hasInternet)
    {
        var subjectsData = FirebaseDatabase
            .DefaultInstance.GetReference("data").Child("0").GetValueAsync();
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => subjectsData.IsCompleted || subjectsData.IsFaulted);
        if (subjectsData.IsCompleted)
        {
            wwwtext = subjectsData.Result.GetRawJsonValue();
            print("text:" + wwwtext);
        }
    }

    print (wwwtext);
    var total_word_local = 0;
    Data _data_online=null;

    if (!wwwtext.Equals(""))
    {
        _data_online = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data>(wwwtext);
        print("data onl: " + _data_online.version.ToString());
    }

    var text_offline = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("data", "");
    Data _data_offline=null;
    if (!text_offline.Equals ("") && text_offline.Contains("subjects")) {
        _data_offline = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data> (text_offline);

    }

    if (_data_offline == null) {
        TextAsset ta = Resources.Load ("data") as TextAsset;
        _data_offline = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data> (ta.text);
    }

    if (_data_online != null) {
        if (_data_online.version > _data_offline.version) {
            data = _data_online;
            PlayerPrefs.SetString ("data", wwwtext);
        } else
            data = _data_offline;
    } else
        data = _data_offline;

    int count_subject = 0;
    foreach (var item in data.subjects) {
        //print(item.brain);
        count_subject++;
        foreach (var u in item.words) {
            total_word_local++;
            string key = item.name + total_word.ToString ();
            item.hint = PlayerPrefs.GetInt (key, 0);
            item.solve=(PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key+"solve",0)==1)?true:false;
            if (count_subject <= 20 || data.version >=20)
                item.show = true;
            else item.show = false;
        }
    }

    total_word = total_word_local;
    Load ();
    Save ();
    ShowMenu ();
    Begin();

    BoardCreate ();

    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("notify",0)==0)
    {
        SendNotification();
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("notify", 1);
    }

}
```

But when I build again, it show this error.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Users\TaiTran\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.1\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/TaiTran/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.unity.purchasing:com.facebook:com.facebook.android:com.google.firebase.unity:com.google.firebase.unity.app:com.google.firebase.auth.api:com.google.firebase.unity.auth:com.google.firebase:com.google.android.gms:com.google.unity:com.unity.purchasing.googleplay:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.v4:com.pixa.findword:com.pushok.test -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\common\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.8.2\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-wrapper-release\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Firebase\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-auth-10.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-common-10.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GooglePlay\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-10.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-10.2.0\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-24.0.0\res" -S "C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res"

stderr[
warning: string 'common_google_play_services_api_unavailable_text' has no default translation.
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values-az-rAZ\common_strings.xml:31: note: locale az-AZ found
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values-en-rAU\common_strings.xml:31: note: locale en-AU found
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values-gu-rIN\common_strings.xml:31: note: locale gu-IN found
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values-pa-rIN\common_strings.xml:31: note: locale pa-IN found
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values-sq-rAL\common_strings.xml:31: note: locale sq-AL found
warning: string 'common_google_play_services_updating_title' has no default translation.
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values-az-rAZ\common_strings.xml:20: note: locale az-AZ found
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values-en-rAU\common_strings.xml:20: note: locale en-AU found
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values-gu-rIN\common_strings.xml:20: note: locale gu-IN found
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values-pa-rIN\common_strings.xml:20: note: locale pa-IN found
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values-sq-rAL\common_strings.xml:20: note: locale sq-AL found
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values\base_attrs.xml:11: error: Attribute "buttonSize" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\res\values\values.xml:47: Original attribute defined here.
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values\base_attrs.xml:16: error: Attribute "colorScheme" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\res\values\values.xml:55: Original attribute defined here.
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_attrs.xml:13: error: Attribute "imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.0\res\values\values.xml:34: Original attribute defined here.
]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)
 mdpi-v4
 hdpi-v4
 xhdpi-v4
 xxhdpi-v4
 xxxhdpi-v4

Files:
  drawable\notify_icon_small.png
    Src: () C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable\notify_icon_small.png
    Src: (mdpi-v4) C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable-mdpi\notify_icon_small.png
    Src: (hdpi-v4) C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable-hdpi\notify_icon_small.png
    Src: (xhdpi-v4) C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable-xhdpi\notify_icon_small.png
    Src: (xxhdpi-v4) C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable-xxhdpi\notify_icon_small.png
    Src: (xxxhdpi-v4) C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\notify_icon_small.png
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
  Type drawable
    drawable\notify_icon_small.png
      Src: () C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable\notify_icon_small.png
      Src: (mdpi-v4) C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable-mdpi\notify_icon_small.png
      Src: (hdpi-v4) C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable-hdpi\notify_icon_small.png
      Src: (xhdpi-v4) C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable-xhdpi\notify_icon_small.png
      Src: (xxhdpi-v4) C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable-xxhdpi\notify_icon_small.png
      Src: (xxxhdpi-v4) C:\Users\TaiTran\Desktop\FindWordBasic\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-android-resources\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\notify_icon_small.png
Including resources from package: C:\Users\TaiTran\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_disabled.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=googleg_disabled_color_18.png
trying overlaySet Key=googleg_standard_color_18.png
trying overlaySet Key=cast_ic_notification_0.png
trying overlaySet Key=cast_ic_notification_1.png
trying overlaySet Key=cast_ic_notification_2.png
trying overlaySet Key=cast_ic_notification_connecting.xml
trying overlaySet Key=cast_ic_notification_on.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
baseFile 0 has flavor hdpi-v4
baseFile 1 has flavor xhdpi-v4
overlayFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
overlayFile 1 has flavor tvdpi-v4
overlayFile 2 has flavor hdpi-v4
overlayFile 3 has flavor xhdpi-v4
overlayFile 4 has flavor xxhdpi-v4
nothing matches overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor mdpi-v4
nothing matches overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor tvdpi-v4
found a match (2) for overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor hdpi-v4
found a match (3) for overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor xhdpi-v4
nothing matches overlay file common_full_open_on_phone.png, for flavor xxhdpi-v4
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
baseFile 0 has flavor 
overlayFile 0 has flavor 
found a match (0) for overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml, for flavor 
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_ic_googleplayservices.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_normal_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_disabled_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_focus_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_normal_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_pressed_dark.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_signin_btn_text_pressed_light.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_medium_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_small_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png
trying overlaySet Key=powered_by_google_dark.png
trying overlaySet Key=powered_by_google_light.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_background.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_icon.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_like_background.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_login_silver_background.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_send_background.xml
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_send_icon.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_close.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_bottomnub.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_topnub.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_xout.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_background.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_bottomnub.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_topnub.png
trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_xout.png
trying overlaySet Key=messenger_bubble_large_blue.png
trying overlaySet Key=messenger_bubble_large_white.png
trying overlaySet Key=messenger_bubble_small_blue.png
trying overlaySet Key=messenger_bubble_small_white.png
trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_blue_bg_round.xml
trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_blue_bg_selector.xml
trying overlaySet Key<message truncated>
```

What is this error mean and how to fix it guys?

Comment: try updating android sdk

Comment: I have updated, but still have error. That error show when I import firebase, maybe something in firebase conflicts which other.